# Link such that deleting any two components leaves an unlink

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Brunnian links are well known, where deleting any component allows you to isotope the rest to an unlink.  It's common to construct them by taking an $n-1$ component unlink and defining the $n$th component as a chain of commutators in the Wirtinger presentation such as $[x_1,[x_2,[x_3,x_4]]]]$

Can you construct $n \ge 4$ component links for any $n$ where deleting any two components leaves an unlink, but the link will not be split after deleting any single component?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, this is done in

*Penney, D.E.*, [**Generalized Brunnian links**](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077378123), Duke Math. J. 36, 31-32 (1969). [ZBL0176.22201](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0176.22201).

Call a link *$(n,k)$-Brunnian* if it has $n$ components, and every sublink with $m$ components: does not split when $k<m\le n$; completely splits when $1\le m\le k$. Then it is shown in the above paper how to use iterated commutators to build an $(n+1,k)$-Brunnian link from an $(n,k)$-Brunnian link.

Comment: Nice! It would be great to have a picture for $(n,k)=(4,2)$, if it exists...

Comment: @YCor: yes, it would. An alternative (earlier) construction is given in [Debrunner, Hans, Links of Brunnian type. Duke Math. J. 28 1961 17–23]. Alas, the pictured link there is $(4,3)$-Brunnian.

Comment: Of course, someone who understands Penney's construction sufficiently well should be able draw a $(4,2)$-Brunnian link by adding a component to the Borromean rings which represents the appropriate product of iterated commutators.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a figure of a (4,2)-Brunnian link (in the terminology of Mark Grant's answer):

[image: figure 5 of Shephard, "Interlinked Loops"]

And here is an image of a (5,3)-Brunnian link:

[image: figure 6 of Shephard, "Interlinked Loops"]

These are taken from G.C. Shephard's 2006 article ["Interlinked Loops"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40378612). He was not aware of the work of Debrunner and Penney at that time as he states essentially this MO question as an open problem.

However, the 2009 followup article ["More Interlinked Loops"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40378722) by W. R. Brakes and G. C. Shephard remedies this by giving a nice pictorial explanation of a version of Penney's construction. Here's an image of a (5,2)-Brunnian link from that paper, where I believe the letters $a,b,c,d$ correspond to elements of the Wirtinger presentation of the fundamental group of the link complement:

[image]

Comment: Lovely pictures!

Comment: It might be a fun project for someone to implement Penney's construction in SageMath.