# Generalized Brunnian links

Tags: knot-theory, knot-link

A *Brunnian link* of order $n$ is nontrivial link of $n$ rings
that becomes a trivial link of $n-1$ rings if any ring is
removed. They were classified up to link-homotopy by
Milnor in 1954. This suggests the following generalization. Let
$\mathcal{A}$ be an antichain of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. In
other words, $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of subsets of
$\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that if $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$ and $A\subseteq B$,
then $A=B$. An *$\mathcal{A}$-link* is a link of $n$ rings
$C_1,\dots,C_n$ such that $\{C_{i_1},\dots,C_{i_j}\}$ is a minimal set
of rings whose removal separates all the remaining rings if and
only if $\{i_1,\dots,i_j\} \in\mathcal{A}$. What can be said about
$\mathcal{A}$-links? For what $\mathcal{A}$ do they exist? For
instance, they obviously don't exist if $\mathcal{A}$ consists of the
single set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Can they be classified analogously to
Milnor's result? There is a special case
[here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299699).